# how to render report data into Email body with footer content using SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

Using SSRS 2008 version,I am generating report to excel which includes two sections in the report.Now i need to schedule Email every two weeks with excel report as attachment and in the same mail include one section in the body along side with footer content.

I am using a stored procedure which gives me report content based on the section I passed.

Please let me know how can I send the email body with one section of the report and add some content as footer to the end of report.